# Save video in every 5 second interval while video recoding is ON (Android OS)

Tags: android, video, video-capture, video-recording, saving-data

I want to save the video every 5 seconds while the video recording is ON.

I have tried many solutions but I am facing a **Glitch** that is, the Last Saved Frame remains in preview for around 300ms.

I think the reason is in MediaRecorder class **"Once a recorder has been stopped, it will need to be completely reconfigured and prepared before being restarted."**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it's impossible to do that with `MediaRecorder`. The better approach could be encoding video by using [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) and storing encoded content bt using [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer).  
[Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) is a project on Google Github account which is a dumping ground for Android graphics & media hacks. In this project, you can find good examples of using both `MediaCodec` and `MediaMuxer` classes. 
I forked the `Grafika` project and did some modifications to support sequential segmented recording. You can find it **[here](https://github.com/mirmilad/grafika)**. When you run the application, select `Show + capture camera` item from the list and then set `Output Segment Duration` for example to 5 and then press `Start recording` button.
Please look at [VideoEncoderCore](https://github.com/mirmilad/grafika/blob/7e16f014fd83b58eb7c01ec9d63ca785a2387344/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/VideoEncoderCore.java#L50) and [CameraCaptureActivity](https://github.com/mirmilad/grafika/blob/7e16f014fd83b58eb7c01ec9d63ca785a2387344/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java) classes source code to find how it works. You can find [here](https://github.com/mirmilad/grafika/blob/7e16f014fd83b58eb7c01ec9d63ca785a2387344/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/VideoEncoderCore.java#L225) how it segments live camera feed to different files.

Comment: Mir Milad Hosseiny, your code is great for slicing video at runtime, but it doesn't record sound. Is it possible to record sound as well?

Comment: @NilsHolgerson look at [this](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample) sample project. It may helps.

Comment: @Uriel Frankel Could u share inputs of ur working code

Comment: @mahesh the link of "here" is exactly what i did

Answer (score 0):

> **"***I think the reason is in MediaRecorder class, `"Once a recorder has been stopped, it will need to be completely reconfigured and prepared before being restarted"`.***"**

You can use multiple `mediaMuxer`'s to encode separate files.

- The camera should send data to fill a MediaMuxer object (which itself produces an `.mp4` file).
- When needed, you can start writing the Camera data to a second (different) MediaMuxer thus automatically creating a second new `.mp4` file (on begin usage of the muxer).
- The first MediaMuxer can then close and save its file. Your first segment is ready...

If needed, try to study this code for a guide on using `Camera` with `mediaMuxer`:
https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt

So you have a function that handles things when the 5 second interval has passed? In that function, could cycle the recording between two muxers, giving one a chance to close its file, while the other records the next segment and then vice-versa).

Instead of something like below (using `MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4`):

```
this.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
```

You will instead create a new muxer (with `MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4`):

```
//# create a new File to ssave into
File outputFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILENAME_DIR, "/yourFolder/Segment" + "-" + mySegmentNum + ".mp4");
String outputPath = outputFile.toString();
int format = MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4;

try { mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputPath, format); } 
catch (IOException e) { Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage()); }
```

And you stop a muxer with:

```
mMuxer1.stop(); mMuxer1.release();
```

**PS:**

Another option is to use **Threads** to run multiple MediaRecorders. It might help your situation. 
See the Android [Background Process](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) guide.